# Binding to Ctrl-Shift in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I want to use AutoHotKey to bind a command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, in the same way that Windows detects it in order to change text direction from right-to-left to left-to-right. That is: I want it to be invoked when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is *let go*, and only if no keys were pressed between pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and letting them go.

I bound a hotkey on ^~ <kbd>Shift</kbd> Up and I expected it to behave the same way as when Windows binds to it for changing the text direction. But, I found that it gets invoked even in cases where I don't want it to be invoked.

For example, I could be selecting a few words by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and then using the arrow keys. Then I let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Shift and the hotkey gets invoked. I don't want this. I want a hotkey that gets invoked only if I held nothing else then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Shift. If I use any other keys, I want the hotkey not to be invoked.

Is there a way to do this with AHK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#InstallKeybdHook

Hotkey, ^LShift Up, ControlShiftUp
Return

ControlShiftUp:
    if (A_PriorKey != "LShift") ; [v1.1.01+]
        return
    ; do something
    msgbox hi
Return
```

Comment: Looks good. It works when it's in its own file, but not when I put it into my existing `.ahk` file, which is how I'd like to use it. Any idea why?

Comment: First I would check if the existing .ahk script runs fine with the required version,v1.1.01, without implementing the code I provided. Second, I would make sure there are no lines that assign hotkeys with LShift. Having said that, without seeing your actual code, I cannot tell. And it's gonna be a different question.

Comment: I've narrowed it down and it turns out that adding even just one simple hotkey, like `#z:: Click 0, 0`, causes your script to not work. I'm baffled. Do you have any idea why this happens?